# Validation not working and Save button is not enabled

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Only if I enter a value in Secondary-phone field, the save button gets enabled and the other issue is secondary phone number needs to be validated but it's not a required field.

```
          <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="float-label active">
                                        <input type="tel" class="input-underline-blue" id="zip" formControlName="zip"
                                               placeholder="@Html.Sitecore().Field("Zip Label", profileItem)*"
                                               (keydown)="numOnlyDown($event)"
                                               (keyup)="numOnlyUp($event)"
                                               required />
                                        <label for="zip">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Zip Label", profileItem)</label>
                                        <div *ngIf="!editInfoForm.get('zip').valid && editInfoForm.get('zip').touched" class="alert alert-danger alert-small">
                                            <span *ngIf="editInfoForm.get('zip').hasError('required')">
                                              Zip Required
                                              @* @Html.Sitecore().Field("Zip Required", profileItemm) *@
                                            </span>
                                            <span *ngIf="editInfoForm.get('zip').hasError('validateZip') && !editInfoForm.get('zip').hasError('required')">
                                              Enter a valid zip code
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="float-label active">
                                        <input type="tel" class="input-underline-blue" id="phone" formControlName="phone"
                                               placeholder="@Html.Sitecore().Field("Phone Label", profileItem)*"
                                               phone
                                               [phoneCountry]="editInfoForm.get('country').value"
                                               (keydown)="numOnlyDown($event)"
                                               (keyup)="numOnlyUp($event)"
                                               [maxlength]="phoneMax"
                                               required />
                                        <label for="phone">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Phone Label", profileItem)</label>
                                        <div *ngIf="!editInfoForm.get('phone').valid && editInfoForm.get('phone').touched" class="alert alert-danger alert-small">
                                            <span *ngIf="editInfoForm.get('phone').hasError('required')">
                                                @Html.Sitecore().Field("Phone Required", profileItem)
                                            </span>
                                            <span *ngIf="!editInfoForm.get('phone').hasError('required') && !editInfoForm.get('phone').valid">
                                                Enter a valid phone number
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="float-label active">
                                        <input type="tel" class="input-underline-blue" id="secondary-phone" formControlName="secondary-phone"
                                               placeholder="@Html.Sitecore().Field("Mobile Phone Label", profileItem)"
                                               phone
                                               [phoneCountry]="editInfoForm.get('country').value"
                                               (keydown)="numOnlyDown($event)"
                                               (keyup)="numOnlyUp($event)"
                                               [maxlength]="phoneMax" />
                                        <label for="secondary-phone">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Mobile Phone Label", profileItem) @Translate.Text("(optional)")</label>
                                        <div *ngIf="!editInfoForm.get('secondary-phone').valid && editInfoForm.get('secondary-phone').touched" class="alert alert-danger alert-small">

                                                Enter a valid phone number

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mv3">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-buttons">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-orange" type="submit" [disabled]="!editInfoForm.valid">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Save Changes Button", profileItem)</button>
                                    <a class="form-link cancel fr fz-sm v-mid" (click)="toggleEditContactInformation()">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Cancel Button", profileItem)</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row section-footer" id="contact-info-footer" *ngIf="editContactInformation === null">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <a class="arrow-link" (click)="toggleEditContactInformation();">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Edit Contact Information", profileItem)</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

@Component({
    selector: 'profile-app',
    templateUrl: '/apps/customer-portal/profile/profile-component',
    providers: [ProfileService, PasswordValidationService, UserService],
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, private profileService: ProfileService, private passwordValidationService: PasswordValidationService) {
    this.editInfoForm = this.fb.group({
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        city: ['', Validators.required],
        country: '',
        state: '',
        email: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            validateEmail
        ]],
        zip: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            validateZip
        ]],
        phone: ['', [
            Validators.required
            // validatePhone
        ]],
        'secondary-phone': ['', 
            validatePhone
        ]

    });
}

toggleEditDetails() {
    this.successPassword = false;
    this.failPassword = false;
    this.successUsername = false;
    this.failUsername = false;

    if (this.editDetails !== null) {
        this.editDetails = null;
        return;
    }
    this.editDetails = new Details();
    Object.assign(this.editDetails, this.details);
}

saveEditDetails() {
    this.whichButton = "details";
    this.save({
        userName: this.editDetails.username,
        contentLanguage: this.editDetails.language
    },
        profile => {
            this.toggleEditDetails();
        });
}


toggleEditCommunicationPreferences() {

    if (this.editCommunicationEmail !== null) {
        this.editCommunicationEmail = null;
        return;
    }
    this.editCommunicationEmail = this.communicationPreferences.email;
}

toggleEditContactInformation() {

    this.successContactInfo = false;
    this.failContactInfo = false;

    if (this.editContactInformation !== null) {
        this.editContactInformation = null;
        return;
    }
    this.editContactInformation = new ContactInformation();
    Object.assign(this.editContactInformation, this.contactInformation);
}

saveEditContactInformation(data: any) {
    this.whichButton = "contactinfo";
    this.save({
        // firstName: data.firstName,
        // lastName: data.lastName,
        // title: data.title,
        mailingStreet: data.street,
        mailingCity: data.city,
        mailingState: data.state,
        mailingPostalCode: data.zip,
        mailingCountry: data.country,
        phone: data.phone,
        mobilePhone: data['secondary-phone'],
        email: data.email
    }, profile => {
        this.toggleEditContactInformation();
    });
}

private save(profile: IProfile, success: (profile: IProfile) => any) {
    if (this.saving)
        return;

    this.saving = true;
    this.profileService.save(profile)
        .then(profile => {
            this.mapProfile(profile);
            success(profile);
            this.saving = false;

            if (this.whichButton === "details") this.successUsername = true;
            if (this.whichButton === "contactinfo") this.successContactInfo = true;

        }).catch(() => {
            this.saving = false;

            if (this.whichButton === "details") this.failUsername = true;
            if (this.whichButton === "contactinfo") this.failContactInfo = true;
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.busy = this.profileService.get()
        .then(profile => {
            this.mapProfile(profile);
            this.editInfoForm.setValue({
                street: profile.mailingStreet,
                city: profile.mailingCity,
                country: profile.mailingCountry,
                state: profile.mailingState,
                email: profile.email,
                zip: profile.mailingPostalCode,
                phone: profile.phone,
                'secondary-phone': profile.mobilePhone
            });
        });
}

formChanged() {
    this.editInfoForm.valueChanges
        .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
}                 

onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if(this.editInfoForm.get('country').value === 'UNITED STATES') {
        this.phoneMax = 12;
        this.editInfoForm.controls['phone'].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12), Validators.maxLength(12)]); // Length 10 digits + 2 '-'
    } else {
        this.phoneMax = null;
        this.editInfoForm.controls['phone'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
    }
    var sSecPhone = '';
    sSecPhone = this.editInfoForm.get('secondary-phone').value;
    if (this.editInfoForm.get('country').value === 'UNITED STATES') {
        this.phoneMax = 12;
        this.editInfoForm.controls['secondary-phone'].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12), Validators.maxLength(12)]); // Length 10 digits + 2 '-'
    } else {
        this.phoneMax = null;
        this.editInfoForm.controls['secondary-phone'].setValidators([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(20)]);
    }

}


ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.formChanged();
}
```

}

thanks
Karthey